# Slow mysql query with LEFT-JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, explain

My website - an online store.
I need to display data from the table of categories.
And count of items in this category.

Number of rows in the table **ITEMS about 6700**.

Number of rows in the table **CATEGORY 123**

I use this query:

```
 SELECT c.* , COUNT( i.id ) count FROM category c  LEFT JOIN items i ON
 i.catid = c.catid  GROUP BY c.id
```

This query is performed for **more than 4 seconds**.

The result of the EXPLAIN:
http://i.gyazo.com/c71c43af2719010cb5c4a2ad1d8cefd8.png

table category:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category ` (   
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`catid` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
`url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
 );
```

table items:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ` items ` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`catid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`link` varchar(255) NOTNULL,
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
`images` text NOT NULL,  
`price` double NOT NULL, 
 `date` datetime NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
);
```

How can I optimize it? please, help

Comment: Run the query using the `Explain` command to help determine if you have any optimization issues. [Explain Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)

Comment: Put an index on catid.

Comment: make catId an INT for both tables, or at least the same type

Comment: @James, good catch. I typically run the explain the command first because it is so easy to use and very quickly tells you where your issue may be.

Comment: I've completed it, but I do not understand what it means. 
Explain: http://i.gyazo.com/c71c43af2719010cb5c4a2ad1d8cefd8.png

Comment: Incidentally, it's unlikely that price would be DOUBLE. See DECIMAL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing category.catid **varchar(16)** with items.catid **int(11)**
will be more faster if you compare **int = int**
deducing that catid is just numbers you can try alter the catid column in category table

```
alter table category modify column catid int(11) NOT NULL;
```

test this code above.

> NOTE: if you have any category.catid greater than **2147483647** you must
>   to change to bigint instead of int.

And if both catid are **not null**, i can understand that no have itens without a catid, then you can change **LEFT JOIN items i ON i.catid = c.catid** by **INNER JOIN items i ON i.catid = c.catid** i dont sure if this will be more fast, but try it.

The ideal was catid be the primary key of category and items.catid a foreign key of category.catid. But to do this, you will need to remove primary key to category.id and add to category.catid, after you can add foreign key items.catid. But just comparing int = int will do diference.

Comment: Thanks!

modify to bigint.
and added index to `catid`.

Time 0.02 seconds.Before that it was 33 seconds with 20000 rows in `items`